# How to create bootstrap grid system with 14 columns?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have 7 elements, I want to show all of them side by side with equal width. I am using bootstrap grid system to place it properly. I can't divide 7 elements into 12 column equally.

Is there anyway that I can create col-lg-14 on my own ?

Comment: Is your entire site needing 14 columns or just this area? Why don't you roll your own just for this situation?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, quite easily. Change @grid-columns to 14 instead of the default, 12, here: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system

Then download this custom boostrap and include it in your `head` instead of the stock bootstrap.

Comment: This is not possible for bootstrap 4 (as far as I know)

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use these classes: d-flex and then flex-fill for the 7 children?

Comment: Simple and should be the accepted answer if you want to apply it in one place and not throughout